# Регулярное выражение для многострочного файла

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text, notepad++

Необходимо составить регулярное выражение для замены в Sublime или Notepad++, которое разобьет текст на блоки подобным образом:

Исходный текст:

```
Котики/
Отсутствует

Котик/
123вап
456пррп
M4501лолд
Mкуе2смив
5646пва1
Г34выаыв42

Котики/
Отсутствует
```

Результат:

```
Котики/\tОтсутствует

Котик/\t123вап\t456пррп\tM4501лолд\tMкуе2смив\t5646пва1\Г34выаыв42

Котики/\tОтсутствует
```

Пример текста, который необходимо обработать за один проход:

```
Котики/
Отсутствует

Отсутствует

Котики

Котики/
Отсутствует

Котики/
Отсутствует

Котики/
Отсутствует

Котики/
Отсутствует

Отсутствует

Котики/
Отсутствует

Котики/
Отсутствует

Котики/
Отсутствует

Котик/
123вап
456пррп
M4501лолд
Mкуе2смив
5646пва1
Г34выаыв42

Котики/
Отсутствует
```

Если кто-то может помочь, был бы благодарен.

Comment: Т.е. найти блок текста, начинающийся с `Котик/\n`, расположенный между `Котики/\nОтсутствует`?

Comment: @AndreiOdegov Наверное, имеется в виду, что необходимо "вытянуть" в одну строку всё, что разделено двумя переносами строки

Comment: @mrcppst, да, все правильно.

Comment: `(.)\R(?!\R)` -> `$1\t`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо, можете оформить в качестве ответа, чтобы поставил плюсик. Это более-менее подходит к тому, что нужно было (сама задача несколько глобальнее, не стал тут описывать).

Comment: Так опишите реальную задачу.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, пошел немного другим путем и сделал это через программу на питоне.Глобальная проблема тоже будет решена с его помощью.

Comment: Если будут проблемы, добавьте комментарий под ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы объединить строки, разделённые одним переносом строки, можно воспользоваться

**Найти**: `(.)\R(?!\R)`
**Заменить на**: `$1\t`

Вместо `\R` можно использовать `\r?\n`, `\r`, `\n` в зависимости от того, какие символы в каждом конкретном файле используются для переноса строки.

**Подробности**

- `(.)` - Подмаска №1: любой символ, отличный от знака переноса строки
- `\R` - любой символ (последовательность символов) переноса строки,
- `(?!\R)` - за которым нет ещё одного переноса строки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]